# from derived class to base class

Tags: c#, class, subclass, simulation

i am trying to create a football simulation program. i have a main class named "team" and 4 derived classes  named "goalKeeper", "defender", "forward" and "midfielder".

i am creating players according to their position.
ex:

```
team fb = new team("fb");
forward alex = new forward(fb.tName, "alex", 73, 77, 77, 69, 70);
```

my team class:

```
  public class team
{
    public string tName;

    public team(string tName)
    {
        this.tName = tName;

    }
    public string teamInfo()
    {
        return tName;
    }
}
```

forward class:

```
class forward:team
{
    //özellikler
    public string pName;
    public string pPosName;
    public int finishing;
    public int longShots;
    public int composure;
    public int offTheBall;
    public int firstTouch;

    public forward(string tName, string pName, int finishing, int longShots, int composure, int offTheBall, int firstTouch)
        : base(tName)
    {
        this.pName = pName;
        this.pPosName = "Forward";
        this.finishing = finishing;
        this.longShots = longShots;
        this.composure = composure;
        this.offTheBall = offTheBall;
        this.firstTouch = firstTouch;

    }

    //etkiyi hesapla
    public double influence
    {
        get
        {
            //calculations

            return processed;
        }
    }

    //futbolcunun genel bilgileri
    public void playerInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "\n##############################\n" + pName + "-" + tName + "-" + pPosName + "\n" + "Finishing= " + finishing + "\n" + "Long Shots= " + longShots + "\n" + "Composure= " + composure + "\n" + "Off the ball= " + offTheBall + "\n" + "Frist Touch= " + firstTouch + "\n##############################\n");
    }
}
```

as you can see i am calculating influence of each player according to their technical attributes.

what i want is automating the process. for example i've created a team.. added players, and i want all player's influence to be called via team name. i am going to give team name and position name and it is gonna give me average influence of players in that team's chosen position.

how can i do this?

thanks in advance...

note: my code might look stupid. i am a newbie :)

Comment: you should only use inheritance to model an is-a relationship (and a few other relationships) a player is not a team so it's generally not a good idea to derive a player from a team

Comment: Some thing you should change right away. A goalkeeper/defender/forward/midfielder is **not** a team, it's a player. Call your base class player, and somewhere you can have a team that consist of a group of player objects.

Comment: Just a thought - wouldn't you consider Forward, GoalKeeper, Midfielder and Defender to be types of *players*. And a team would then be a *collection* of players?

Comment: Listen to ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen and RuneFS. They're right on point. You've got the crux of inheritance wrong.

Comment: thank you guys. i will change the interitance order.

Comment: Hey there newb, welcome to C#. In addition to the others' good comments on getting the inheritance relationships right, now is also a good time to get into good habits of naming and code organization. In C# it is the usual practice to CapitalizeYourClassAndPropertyNames, so that should be `class Team` and `public double Influence`. Also, try to avoid public fields; you can make a public property that backs a field easily like this: `public string Name { get; private set; }` -- and that has the advantage that only your class can set the name.

Comment: Also, avoid putting prefixes on names. It should be `Name`, or perhaps `TeamName` (but having a Name property on class Team makes it pretty clear that its the team name!)  It should under no circumstances be `tName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A player is not a team, this would give you an idea

```
public class Team
{
  private IList<Player> _players
  ...
}

public class Player
{
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public abstract Influence { get; }
}

public class Forward : Player
{
  public override Influence
  {
    get { return //calculation }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A forward IS A team?
Not at all... A team HAS A forward...

Dont use inheritance... use composition instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rethinking your inheritence strategy.
When a class inherits another this implies that the child class 'is a' base class. Applying this to your model implies that a forward 'is a' team which doesn't make much sense. In reality a team 'has a' forward(s).
A more accurate model for what you are trying to achieve is to have a player class as your base class that your foward class, defender class etc inherits from. Your team class can then contains a collection of player classes.